# Selenium Java: How can I get the value

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a Catalogue Number text field, which has a value = Pen populated.
When I inspect the element in DOM tree, the textfield value is data bind.
How can I get the data bind value and verify the textfield is not empty using Selenium Java?

```
<input id="txtCatalogueNo" class="k-textbox" maxlength="25" data-bind="value: selectedCatalogue.CatalogueNumber">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
WebElement TxtBoxContent = driver.findElement(By.id("txtCatalogueNo"));
System.out.println(TxtBoxContent.getAttribute("value"));
```

or

```
WebElement TxtBoxContent = driver.findElement(By.id("txtCatalogueNo"));
System.out.println(TxtBoxContent.getText());
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It give me java.lang.AssertionError: expected [Pen] but found []

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of any attribute of a WebElement using `getAttribute` method.

If `data-bind` attribute contains the value,

```
WebElement TxtBox = driver.findElement(By.id(txtCatalogueNo));
System.out.println(TxtBox.getAttribute("data-bind")); // to get the value in data-bind attribute.
```

If `Value` attribute contains the value:

```
System.out.println(TxtBox.getAttribute("value")); // to get the value in data-bind attribute.
```

you can retrieve the test using `getText` method

```
System.out.println(TxtBox.getText()); // to get the text
```

Comment: I tried both methods. I get java.lang.AssertionError: expected [Pen] but found [] if I use getText() method. I get java.lang.AssertionError: expected [Pen] but found [value: selectedCatalogue.CatalogueNumber] if I use method getAttribute("data-bind")

Comment: Yes, that is what you expected right? When there no value (Pen) in textfield you get above mentioned values. If value is present then You will get Pen. Am I correct? If yes, the issue is already solved, as you are getting getText empy value, which is TRUE.

Comment: Sorry no. There is value (Pen) populated in the textfield. When I use FireBug to inspect the textfield, Pen is not shown in DOM tree. It is showing data-bind="value: selectedCatalogue.CatalogueCatalogueNumber"> I want to use Assert.assetEquals to verify the textfield actually populated value (Pen)

Comment: can you please share the screenshot of web page highlighting the input text field (Pen) by Firebug that shows correponding HTML page?

Comment: Here is the app I am working on the automation test URL: Here is the URL: http://app.mex.com.au/MEXTrial After seeing the Main Menu, click on Stores button -> Click on Catalogue -> Open any catalogue details. You won't be able to find Pen. It is because it is using different db.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebElement TxtBox = driver.findElement(By.id("txtCatalogueNo"));
String valueTxtBox=TxtBox.getAttribute("data-bind").split(":")[1].trim();
System.out.println(valueTxtBox);
```

OR

```
WebElement TxtBox = driver.findElement(By.id("txtCatalogueNo"));
String valueTxtBox=TxtBox.getAttribute("data-bind").replace("value: ", "");
System.out.println(valueTxtBox);
```

`valueTxtBox` will contain the value you are looking for.

Comment: I tried both method. They both return java.lang.AssertionError: expected [Pen] but found [selectedCatalogue.CatalogueNumber]

Comment: @B.Tang are you able to perform sendKeys() operation on the text-box??

Comment: Yes. Here is the URL: http://http://app.mex.com.au/MEXTrial/ After seeing the Main Menu, click on Stores button -> Click on Catalogue -> Open any catalogue details. You won't be able to find Pen. It is because it is using different db. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply on this its pretty simple. I'll just assume you are using angular.

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.id("txtCatalogueNo"));
String content = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
        .executeScript("return arguments[0].value", element);
```

Hopefully this works for you.