# Use Selenium to get input element value, if it isn't in HTML?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Is there any way to read the text in an input without calling to get it from HTML? In the image, I want to get whatever value I can from the input, store it, then add a number to it, but it's not in the HTML(the input just refers to "quantity"

[image: Not represented in HTML]

Is there some way I could select the input box, copy the value, then interact with the value from there?

Comment: This ans from stackoverflow may help. It is in Java,but try to implement in python.
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624766/selenium-java-how-can-i-get-the-value#:~:text=You%20can%20get%20the%20value,.id(txtCatalogueNo))%3B%20System.

Comment: Won't help unfortunately. The input has no value for the input. It's kept in the data-bind as some kind of variable, "quantity" which is also represented in other rows. Not sure how I would be able to even read it from HTML. From what I can tell, it's from knockout.js, which is intentionally making it hard to scrape it just from HTML.

Answer (score 0):

To print the text i.e. ***1*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.validation-message-container > input[data-bind*='isForwardFreightSeller']"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='validation-message-container']/input[contains(@data-bind, 'isForwardFreightSeller')]"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I've already tried this. Value is not on the HTML, so all that prints is an empty line. Is there a way to highlight the textbox and copy from it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the following javascript snippet for this:

```
return arguments[0].value;
```

This is assuming you know how to execute javascript on an element.

Comment: I've already tried this. Value is not on the HTML, so it would only return the javascript equivalent of None.